# Perl - SSH daemon package

Tags: perl, sshd

Do we have any Server module like HTTP::Daemon for SSH?

I tried searching CPAN but no luck.

Comment: What do you try to do in the end? OpenSSH (and probably most other SSH servers) can be customized to run any command you want to handle new connections.